# Subtracting two queries from each other in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails, and even ruby, so I'm having some trouble figuring this out.

I want to find the difference between two queries. This particular query should return a single record, since I've set it up such that Recipe is missing one of the IDs from recipes.
Current code:

```
q = Recipe.all - Recipe.where(recipe_id: recipes)
```

Where recipes is an array of IDs.

From my limited understanding of the language, this would work if both Recipe.all and Recipe.where both returned arrays.

I've spent some time searching the web, with nothing coming up to aid me.

Other things I've tried:

```
q = [Recipe.all] - [Recipe.where(recipe_id: recipes)]
q = Recipe.where.not(recipe_id: recipes) # Wouldn't work because the array is the one with the extra id
```

Though neither proved helpful.

Comment: Turns out I was asking the wrong question. Since the array of IDs is the one with the extra records, I should have been comparing the difference of that array with the result of Recipe.where. I'm not sure how to amend this, but I'll put my answer in the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I was asking the wrong question.

Since the array of IDs is the one with extra elements, not the database query, I should have been comparing the difference of it to the query.

My answer is as follows:

```
q = recipes - Recipe.where(recipe_id: recipes).ids
```

Which returns the missing IDs.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
q = Recipe.where('recipe_id NOT IN (?)', recipes)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Rails 4, you can use the [not query method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/WhereChain.html#method-i-not)

```
q = Recipe.where.not(id: recipes)
```

this will generator following query:

```
SELECT "recipes".* FROM "recipes" WHERE ("recipes"."id" NOT IN (12, 8, 11, 5, 6, 7))
```